# php built-in server 0.0.0.0 empty response

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, server

hi i tried to running php built-in server with passthru()

```
<?php
passthru("php -S 0.0.0.0:8080");
```

then I executed program from terminal

```
php script.php
```

with no error, but i can't access the http://hostname:8080 that's different when i write command directly in terminal

```
$ php -S 0.0.0.0:8080
```

is something wrong?
I'm using Ubuntu

Comment: localhost::8080

Comment: Would `passthru` also forward the standard error stream? I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding this, but what exactly are you trying to do? Starting a webserver via passthru seems like a strange approach.

Comment: @hassan when open with http://localhost:8080 work but I would like to open with http://hostname:8080

Comment: @iainn yes is similar to laravel artisan serve

Comment: @user8212655 you will need to set-up an apache2 virtual host.

Comment: note: I run this on vps, when tried curl http://localhost:8080 its work but when curl http://hostname:8080 no work